# How is chrome storage affected when an extension is updated?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If a user adds data to an extensions `chrome.storage.local/sync` the extension then gets updated because a new version is released. Will the `chrome.storage.local/sync` still be the same or will it reset?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it will be the same.

It's actually quite common to have some "schema version" variable inside storage that you can use to upgrade the storage if your data format changes with an update.

However, it's important to remember that uninstalling an extension will completely wipe the storage, **including** the `sync` storage if Sync is enabled.

Comment: also, removing profile will wipe stored data from extensions (including extensions) on that particular profile

Comment: @vux777 `storage.sync` will survive if the local profile is deleted, though. One of the many advantages..

Comment: because of the "cloud" thing, right? locally, they will be wiped, and if user creates new profile with same sync acc, then it will sync...or there is another mechanism for this? Plus, sync is not very useful for extensions data, very limited in size...

Comment: Maybe we can use local storage and cloud asynchronously with local first approach? I have never used storage API, but if it is the same way with the HTML5, we can create a sufficient storage management.

Answer (score 0):

If `chrome.storage.sync.set` is not called when the extension is updated, then the old data remains.

If the state key value changes during the update, the data needs to be cleared, otherwise a lot of discarded values will accumulate.

```js
const initData = { a: 10, b: 20 };

// Use old value if there is one
// If a new value is added, the value of `initData` is used by default
chrome.storage.sync.get(dataRaw => { 
  const data = Object.entries(initData).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    return { ...acc, [k]: dataRaw[k] === undefined ? v : dataRaw[k] };
  }, {});
 // Clean up unwanted data
  chrome.storage.sync.clear(() => chrome.storage.sync.set(data));
});
```